# postgis How can I obtain directional buffer?

Tags: postgis, buffer, direction

I have a geometry (polygon) which I want to extend with a buffer while testing on it in a where clause. The problem is that I would like the buffer to be only applied according to one or more directions (e.g. North and East) and not in all directions. Is there a way to do it combining operators into a single query? If not, how would it be feasible with a stored procedure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Use [ST_Affine](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Affine.html) to make a shifted geometry;
2. Use [ST_ConvexHull](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_ConvexHull.html) on each pair (original and shifted) to create a "directional buffer".

Comment: The convex hull seems inadequate for creating the buffer as it appears to also "buffer out" irregularities in the geometry in unwanted directions. The union of several shifted geometries seems to do the trick pretty well as probably would also a concave_hull with adequate percent

Answer (score 1):

I didn't quite understood how to use ST_Affine to complete this task, but only shifting the geometry was not enough and convexhull would distort the geometry, so I'm sorry if it is out of topic.

My solution was quite straight forward:

1. create Union of Original and Shifted geometry
2. DumpPoints from Original geom, shift them in desired direction by desired distance
3. create lines which will connect the original position and shifted position of the point
4. Union this directional lines with the Boundary of Unioned polygon
5. and BuildArea with it

[image: comparison of construction of directional buffer]

I have it in a function, where the _geom, _point_distance_m are declared:

```
WITH w_only_shifted AS (
            SELECT
                ST_Union(
                    _geom,
                    ST_Translate(_geom, -_point_distance_m, -_point_distance_m)
                ) AS geom
            )
        ,w_original_points AS (
            SELECT
                ST_DumpPoints(geom) AS dp
            FROM
                (SELECT _geom AS geom) AS t1
            )
        ,w_dumped AS (
            SELECT
                (dp).path, (dp).geom
            FROM
                w_original_points
            )
        ,w_coordinates AS (
            SELECT
                st_x(geom) AS x, st_y(geom) AS y, geom, path
            FROM
                w_dumped
            )
        ,w_shift_points AS (
            SELECT
                path,
                x, y, geom,
                x-_point_distance_m AS x_shift,
                y-_point_distance_m AS y_shift,
                ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(x-_point_distance_m, y-_point_distance_m),3035) AS geom_shift
            FROM
                w_coordinates
        )
        ,w_make_line AS (
            SELECT
                ST_Union(ST_MakeLine(geom,geom_shift)) AS line
            FROM 
                w_shift_points
            )
        ,w_union_all AS (
            SELECT
                ST_Union(t1.line, ST_Boundary(t2.geom)) AS all_lines
            FROM
                w_make_line AS t1,
                w_only_shifted AS t2
            )
        SELECT
            ST_buildarea(all_lines)
        FROM
            w_union_all;
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understad what you are trying to do, there should be more efficient ways than dealing with buffer.

ST_Dwithin is recomended instead of buffer->intersects

If you combine ST_Dwithin with an directional operator, you should be able to do what you want ( if I don't miss you intentions)
http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.2/reference.html#Operators

Comment: I do not get the logic of it, can you clarify with a step by step example of such a combination? The equivalent of buffering in north and east directions only for example

Comment: I think what is being suggested is something like "where distance(A,B) = 0 OR (distance(A,B) < buffer AND A is north of B OR A is East of B)" however the postgis operators for left of/right of/etc only work on bounding boxes, not actual geometries, and the definition of them is ambiguous in the case of actual geometries in many cases (often when one geometry wraps around the other to some degree). I'm not certain that there is a way to do what you what without implementing a directional buffer operation.